# Virtual Env on Mac with python 3.4

Tags: python, macos, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to get a django project up and running, and I have django running, but I am having trouble with python's virtualenv.

here is my error (on terminal open this shows up)

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Here is what My .bash profile looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

I am pretty new to command line stuff and virtual environments, so I might not know some "obvious" things I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Try to comment `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}` and the next line

Comment: Same errors. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you tried specifying which python version you want to use with `mkvirtualenv --python /path/to/python3.4 venv_name` ?

Comment: This is one of the things that I have been wrestling with forever, how to get virtualenv to target different versions of python. I will try this in a bit, thanks!

Comment: Shameless plug: if virtualenvwrapper is giving you problems, maybe you could try with my own Pew? https://github.com/berdario/pew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some basics of the command-line shell:

PATH is an environment variable that contains a list of filesystem directories. When you type a command such as `ls`, `python` or `virtualenvwrapper.sh` your shell will search each directory starting from the first one listed. To see your current PATH type:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

To see what a given command is going to resolve to the location of the program that is going to be run, use the `which` command:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Now in your example you are first adding a Python 3.4 location to your PATH and then a Python 2.7 location. The latter location is going to be first on your PATH. So all your Python related commands are first going to try and run Python 2.7, if a command isn't found there, it next searches in your Python 3.4 installation.

You appear to have installed `virtualenvwrapper` for Python 3.4, but when you run virtualenvwrapper.sh from the line:

```
source     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

You are explicitly running the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` installed for Python 3.4. This runs a `python` command where your Python 2.7 is run, which does not appear to have `virtualenvwrapper` installed, as shown by this error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
```

If you tried removing the Python 2.7 location addition to your PATH and it didn't work, you have to remember that changes to your `.bash_profile` are not automatically reflected in your terminal. You have to create a new terminal session and that new session will read your new `.bash_profile`.

If you are trying to get the command `virtualenv` to resolve to two different Pythons, it's simply not possible. It will always resolve to one specific Python based on the ordering of the locations on your PATH. VirtualEnv does install alternate versions of the command with the version of the Python built into the name. Use the commands `virtualenv-3.4` and `virtualenv-2.7` to create virtual environments for each different Python.

The key to all of this is remembering that PATH is used to resolve to an absolute path location of a program this is run. Use the `echo $PATH` and `which` commands to help you understand how that final path is being resolved.

It may seem tedious, but typing out the full absolute path is always going to side-step the magic of PATH resolution:

```
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
```

Try using smaller steps on your way to manipulating the path. Use just `virutalenv-3.4` to make a Python 3.4 virtual environment and only bring in `virtualenvwrapper` as you need it and after your understanding of shell environments is more solid.

Finally, even pro's can get tripped up by playing games manipulating the path. You are ultimately trying to take a bunch of different application locations and flatten them all into one namespace. At some point conflicts can become unresolveable. A Python installation tool such as `Buildout` has it's own learning curve, but it hard-codes the absolute path to the python of each python script that it installs. Hard-coding absolute paths is the only way to deal with extreme corner cases such as having two builds of Python 3.4 side-by-side where you have two scripts which each need to run on two different builds of the same Python. Hard-coding absolute locations is also desirable in production environments, because then your application is immune to any changes to the bash shell. If you forget about a required ordering of your PATH, or another sysadmin tinkers with the PATH, you won't find your application breaking unexpectedly.